# Can I somehow increase the size of USB Endpoint?

Tags: java, android, usb

Here's the code that I wrote to open up the USB device

```
private void openDevice(UsbDevice device){
    Log.v(TAG, "USB device setup initiated");
    Map<String, UsbDevice> connectedDevices = usbManager.getDeviceList();

    if (!connectedDevices.isEmpty()) {
        if (device.getVendorId() == USB_VENDOR_ID && device.getProductId() == USB_PRODUCT_ID) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Device found: " + device.getDeviceName());
            Log.i(TAG, "Ready to open USB device connection");
            connection = usbManager.openDevice(this.device);
            intface = this.device.getInterface(0);
            connection.claimInterface(intface, true);
            USBisOpen = true;
            Log.v(TAG, "USB is Opened");
        }
    }
}
```

and here's the code I wrote to open up the Endpoint.

```
for(int i = 0; i < intface.getEndpointCount(); ++i){
    endpoint = intface.getEndpoint(i);
    if(endpoint.getType() == UsbConstants.USB_ENDPOINT_XFER_BULK && endpoint.getDirection() == UsbConstants.USB_DIR_IN){
        Log.v(TAG, "endpoint index is " + i);
        break;
}
                        }
Log.v(TAG, "Transferable Buffer Size is: " + endpoint.getMaxPacketSize());
```

So, I'm curious about the 'getMaxPacketSize()' method.
Is there a way that somehow I can manipulate the size of it? I found this constructor code in the class

```
public UsbEndpoint(int address, int attributes, int maxPacketSize, int interval) {
    mAddress = address;
    mAttributes = attributes;
    mMaxPacketSize = maxPacketSize;
    mInterval = interval;
}
```

but it seems that I can't utilize it like this

```
 UsbEndpoint endpoint = new UsbEndpoint(address, attributes, size, interval);
```

the comment in the code says 'UsbEndpoint should only be instantiated by UsbService implementation' and is this anything to do with this?

Thank you for reading my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The maximum packet size of an endpoint is a property of the firmware of the USB device.  If you are able to modify the firmware, then you could change maximum packet sizes, but that can be a complicated process and is usually not possible for most USB devices.

A typical PC operating system reads USB descriptors from the device in order to figure out the maximum packet size for each endpoint.  Proper USB drivers will then use these maximum packet sizes to ensure that communication with the device will work properly.

Answer (score 1):

MAX size of an endpoint is USB specification defined parameter.
You can not change Endpoint size (max packet size) of a device. As per specification, following are the max sizes -

**USB 3.0**

Bulk - 1024 bytes
Control - 512 bytes
Isochronous - 1024 bytes
Interrupt - 1024 bytes

**USB 2.0** (High speed)

Bulk - 512 bytes
Control - 64 bytes
Isochronous - 1024 bytes
Interrupt - 1024 bytes

Comment: FYI: USB 1.1 and 2.0 "Full Speed" Bulk and Interrupt EPs are 64 bytes max. Low speed maximum is only 8 bytes.

Comment: @TurboJ Thanks updated the comment to make it clearer.